# How do I mount executable permissions to a flash drive? (Steam)

Tags: usb-drive, steam

I recently installed Gallium OS on my chromebook for the purpose of gaming. I have a Lenovo N21 Chromebook. I downloaded Steam and had enough space leftover for Terraria (Game). It runs smoothly, and people have been telling me that Minecraft and CSGO (Counter-Strike Global Offensive) could run on this device. However, my chromebook did not have enough space leftover for CSGO. I bought a 62 gb flash drive for the storage and tried downloading CSGO. When I clicked "play now", it gave me the option to install under the flash drive. When I clicked the flash drive file and hit install, an error came up saying "New Steam Library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with exectuable permissions." Now, I'm not a computer/technological person, so I have absolutely no clue how to proceed. If anyone could help me with this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Either one of these two commands will work. Make sure your either in the right directory or use the full path to the directory/filename where the USB stick is mounted.

```
$ chmod 755 filename
$ chmod u=rwx filename
```

Comment: I typed in both commands seperately and it came up saying "cannot access 'filename': no such file or directory"

Comment: did you run the command as the root user? Get a (Root-capable) Shell
Once in developer mode, there are two ways to get a root-capable shell, which is required for doing anything useful:
On the login screen, press [CTRL+ALT+F2] (F2 is right-arrow on ChromeOS keyboards), then login with user 'chronos' (no password is required, nor should one be set)
When logged in (as a guest is ok) and with a browser window open, press [CTRL+ALT+T], then type shell and press enter now try to run either one of the commandsI listedand see what that does.

Comment: Nevermind guys, I fixed the problem on my own. Thanks so much for your suggestions though!!

Comment: Feel free to write an answer to your own question to describe the fix that actually worked, and mark it as accepted. It might help someone else that has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the removable media mounting tools of your desktop environment to mount the flash drive, the drive is most likely using its factory default filesystem (most likely FAT32 or NTFS, depending on size) unless you reinitialized it, and is now mounted with a `noexec` mount option (or the `user` option that implies mount options `noexec,nosuid,nodev`) that was set automatically by the media mounting tool. If so, that is not overrideable with a `chmod` command.

Instead, you would have to configure your mount point in `/etc/fstab` with a suitable set of mount options.

You might want to specify the filesystem UUID instead of the device name, so that the `/etc/fstab` entry will work regardless of whether you have other USB storage devices plugged in or not. To do that, first use the output of `df` to identify the current device name of the flash drive when it's mounted, then `sudo blkid` to find out the UUID corresponding to the device name.

The necessary `/etc/fstab` entry would be something like this:

```
UUID="your-UUID-here" /desired/mount/point auto rw,noauto,user,exec 0 0
```

if you want to mount the flash drive yourself whenever you use it. If you want it to auto-mount if it's plugged in at boot time, replace `noauto` with `nofail`:

```
UUID="your-UUID-here" /desired/mount/point auto rw,nofail,user,exec 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, but there are a lot of concepts here that I don't understand. I will try to find someone who can help me through this in person.